# Show that for any two Cauchy sequences of rational numbers, their difference is a equivalent to a sequence of nonnegative numbers

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a_n$ and $b_n$ be Cauchy sequences of rational numbers, either $b_n-a_n$ or $a_n-b_n$ is a sequence of nonnegative numbers.

I don't really understand how this is true, I think first we have to assum $a_n\neq b_n$. If we assume that they are not the same sequence, how does this work?

Comment: Cauchy sequence 1: 0,0,0,0.... Cauchy sequence 2: +1/2, -1/4, +1/8, -1/16, +1/32 ...  What am I missing?

Comment: @PeterWebb The first sentence disagrees with the title.  We're looking for a non-negative sequence that is equivalent to $b_n-a_n$ or $a_n-b_n$.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to assume that the sequences are not the same; if they are then $b_n - a_n$ is the zero sequence, which is nonnegative.

Let $x$ be the real number represented by the Cauchy sequence $b_n - a_n$. Then either $b_n - a_n$ or $a_n - b_n$ represents the nonnegative real number $|x|$. Recall that Cauchy sequences are equivalent when they represent the same real number. So you have to find a nonnegative Cauchy sequence that represents the real number $|x|$.

Answer (score 1):

We don't have to assume $a_n\ne b_n$.  Let $c_n=a_n-b_n$.  If $a_n=b_n$ for all $n$, then $c_n=0$ for all $n$.  Remember that non-negative doesn't mean positive, it means $\ge 0$.

If $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ are Cauchy sequences, then they both converge, let
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=1\quad\text{and}\quad\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=b.$$  Now, either
$a\le b$ or $b\le a.$

Suppose $a\ge b$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n-b_n)=a-b\ge 0$.  So, what can you say about $a_n-b_n$ if $n$ is large enough?

Comment: Ok that was trivial but thanks for pointing it out.. can you give a hint for the next step?

Comment: Sure.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: if $a\leq b$, how is $a-b \geq 0$?

Comment: Whoops, I'll fix that. :)

Comment: If $n$ is large enough, $a_n-b_n$ is an infinite sequence?

Comment: Well the sequence is approaching a non-negative number.  So, eventually for large enough $n$ all the terms will be non-negative.

Comment: Actually if we assume they are not equivalent sequences, then can we say either $a>b$ or $a<b$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

This sentence with

> either $b_n-a_n$ or $a_n-b_n$ is a sequence of nonnegative numbers

is not true in this form: you can modify the first some elements of a sequence anyhow without affecting its being Cauchy. What is true, is either

1. one of the sequences $b_n-a_n$ and $a_n-b_n$ is equivalent to (=has the same limit as) a Cauchy sequence of nonnegative (rational) numbers.

as Arthur answered, or

2. there is an index $N$ such that one of $a_n-b_n$ and $b_n-a_n$ is nonnegative for all $n>N$.

Comment: The correct question is in the title. Good point nonetheless.

Comment: Option 2 may not hold, as Peter Web noticed.